# How to do ng-repeat in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem with nesting `ng-repeat`. I'm new to *AngularJS* so maybe I don't understand the concept.

I need to show GROUPS and in it I need to show ITEMS which have `GROUP_ID` like `GROUP`.

I know how to do it in *PHP* but I need to do it in *AngularJS*.

This is how I would to it in *PHP*:

```
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY position ASC");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<h1>',$row['name'],'</h1>';

    $items=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE group_id='".$row['id']."'");
    while ($itemsrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($items)) {
        echo '<p>',$itemsrow['name'],'</p>';
    }
}
```

I tried to `ng-repeat` in `ng-repeat` but I don't know how to access `GROUP_ID` from actual GROUP. I hope you know what I mean. Anybody can help?

Comment: Can you provide the JSON you are trying to display?

Comment: I've tried to get GROUPS first and after that ITEMS. That is why I have two JSONs data.
First:
`[{"id":"1","name":"Silnik","position":"0"},{"id":"2","name":"Podajnik","position":"1"}]`

Second looks the same but it has other values

Comment: **Provide** your JSON data(s), please.

Comment: you need to have an array of array to use ng-repeat inside ng-repeat.

structure your data that way and it's a cake walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups track by group.id">
  <h1 ng-bind="group.name"></h1>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {group_id: group.id} track by $index">
    <div ng-bind="item.name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EhjvrFm5c0NSSf0Vwnk2?p=preview

Comment: I have problem now. I changed **track by item.position** and it works but... This is my JSON:
`3: {id: "3", group: "1", name: "temp1", type: "temp"}
4: {id: "4", group: "2", name: "pa1", type: "pascal"}
5: {id: "5", group: "2", name: "temp_zb", type: "temp"}`
Only thing I changed is number of object (3,4,5) which before was position of item, but now I want to do unique number ID. Now I have error: ** [filter:notarray]** Why it doesn't work. I didn't change anything in angular - only in JSON - numbers are different.

Comment: I updated my plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/EhjvrFm5c0NSSf0Vwnk2?p=preview) with your object and it works properly. Please fork my plunker and reproduce your issue and I will try to help